# CSS Slider Revolution - Layers need to show at something specific in the picture

Tags: html, css, slider, typo3, revolution-slider

I'm using the [Revolution Slider](https://www.rutschmann.biz/extensions/typo3-slider-revolution/) for TYPO3.

Inside my slider I have arrows which show at something specific in the picture. But as soon as I change the screen size, the picture changes it size and the arrows don't fit anymore.

[Here's the website](http://cms.tabs-spezialreinigung.de/index.php?id=4&no_cache=1) (talking about the heroslider)

Is there an easy solution?

Help would be very appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy solution because with the current setup of your slider the overlay information will be resized in proportion. On small screens like smartphones the content must be arranged completely different to be able to read it. That's why such sliders are not really responsive because resizing is not always a solution. Maybe it's better to hide replace the slider on small devices with another concept or hide the overlay information with css media queries.